# OpenSSL issue with Laravel on WAMP 2.2

Tags: php, openssl, wamp

I've been having this issue for a few days now and it is really starting to annoy me as I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Anyways, I am trying to set up a `laravel`project on my `localhost`. First thing I do is this:

`composer create-project laravel/larvel test-project`

This does the various set up of components for the framework and creates a project in my `web root`. Following this I navigate to this `URL`

```
http://localhost/test-project/public/
```

And as expected I get the `laravel`welcome page to show my project has been successfully setup. However when I refresh the page I get the following error which is related to the `openSSL` module:

```
RuntimeException thrown with message "OpenSSL extension is required."

Stacktrace:
#8 RuntimeException in C:\wamp\www\test-project\bootstrap\compiled.php:8375
#7 Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter:validMac in C:\wamp\www\test-project\bootstrap\compiled.php:8367
#6 Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter:getJsonPayload in C:\wamp\www\test-project\bootstrap\compiled.php:8348
#5 Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter:decrypt in C:\wamp\www\test-project\bootstrap\compiled.php:8271
#4 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:decryptCookie in C:\wamp\www\test-project\bootstrap\compiled.php:8262
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:decrypt in C:\wamp\www\test-project\bootstrap\compiled.php:8256
#2 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in C:\wamp\www\test-project\bootstrap\compiled.php:10895
#1 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in C:\wamp\www\test-project\bootstrap\compiled.php:659
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:run in C:\wamp\www\test-project\public\index.php:49
```

Now the problem I am having is this. I've ensured that `openSSL` is infact activated. I did this by running the following command `php --ini` which showed me the path to the `php.ini` file that `composer`would have used to create the project. It resides in the following directory:

```
C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/
```

I uncommented this line:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

and restarted `WAMP` but the problem persists. I am wondering if anyone can shed some light onto this incredibly annoying situation as I believe I've been careful to ensure that the neccessary components where installed before creating my project.

I know that apache uses a different  `php.ini` file and just to make sure that wasn't the issue I've also unccomented the same line (Above). However from what I understand when using `composer` to create projects It does not use this `php.ini`.

If you need any more information I'd be happy to provide it. I seem to have exhausted all options except for a fresh install of `WAMP` which I'd rather not have to do. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Laravel. It is an webserver configuration issue.

Comment: @Delmadord I think you'll find it is completely to do with laravel seen as the issue is my laravel project wont load up and it's also completely to do with programming because the issue lies within my `php.ini` file.

Comment: No, the exception in similar form could be thrown by anything relying on the OpenSSL. OpenSSL must be installed too, it will not work only by enabling the PHP extension for it. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do it on the Windows box.

Comment: @Javacadabra Did you get the solution for it???I am also facing the above issue..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841430/laravel-exception-after-cookie-is-set-openssl-extension-is-required

Answer (score 1):

Ok the first thing you need to know is that there are 2 php.ini files in WampServer.

**ONE** in `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/php.ini` and this one is used when you use the PHPCLI (Command line Interface) i.e. when you run

```
composer create-project laravel/larvel test-project
```

So if the php.exe CLI needs access to specific extensions you have to edit this one.

**TWO** there is also one in the `\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\bin` folder. This is the one that gets used by Apache, and is edited when you use the wampmanager menus and you should use the menus to get to it as this ensures you are editing the correct file.

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

So if the website needs access to specific extensions you have to edit this one

So I imaging you have edited the wrong file, but thats easy to fix.

Once the correct file is edited to activate openssl, your next issue may be that these 2 files may need copying from the `PHP` folder to the `apachex.y.z/bin` folder. Make sure you do a copy and not a move as they are also required in the PHP folder for the CLI.

```
libeay32.dll
ssleay32.dll
```

Once that is done you should be good to go.

Comment: I think that may be my issue! I'm in work at the moment so cannot check but I'm almost sure that is what it is, i'll try it later and give an update. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried that, the files already existed in the apache bin. Just to make sure I copied and overwrote anyways and no joy....the weird thing is every time I start up WAMP the project works first time I load it in the browser. When I refresh the page I get the problem!!!