# Laravel Exception after page is refresh - OpenSSL extension is required

Tags: exception, laravel-4, runtime-error

I am newbie in Laravel. I am using windows 7. I have downloaded and created a laravel project inside xampp inside htdocs folder.I have uncommented the statement,`extension=php_openssl.dll` inside `php.ini`. When I type the `http://localhost/laravel/public/` in the browser, it shows the home page. When I refresh the page I get an exception like this.

[image]

When I remove the cookies and session variables in the browser settings, it will show the home page for once and if I refresh the page after,it shows the above page again.

**NB: I have edited nothing in the project.I just tried to run the project**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After uncommenting the line in the php.ini file, you must still activate it: left click on the WAMP server icon, then *PHP-> PHP extensions* and ensure that **php_openssl** is checked. If not, click it. WAMP will restart and it should be OK.